# Chrome Custom Tabs, deep linking with Oauth2

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, deep-linking, chrome-custom-tabs

Hi I'm using Google Chrome Custom Tabs for a project and I have a few issues with deep linking.

I need to authenticate the users through a oauth2 process using chrome custom tabs. The user is sent to the authentication form then types is login/password. Then it is redirected to a url like `myapp://something`. An intent is then triggered and the user is sent back to the app.

The process is working well at first launch when the user is logging in through the authentication form. However, if I try to get another authentication code, I get an `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` error and the app stays on the custom tabs.

Here are the three cases I tested :

**1st case : Chrome custom tab, forcing the user to use the authentication form**

-The user is sent to the authentication form

-A 302 redirect is done to a custom url

-The user is switched to the app

**2nd case : Chrome custom tab (using the session cookie)**

-The user is sent to the authentication website

-A 302 redirect is done to a custom url

-An `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` occurs

**3rd case : Chrome browser (using the authentication form or the session cookie)**

-The user is sent to the authentication website

-A 302 redirect is done to a custom url

-The user is switched to the app

The full process is working with the chrome browser but I have to make it work with Custom Tabs. Is this behaviour normal ? I mean i read that a user interaction might be needed to use deep links but everything is working well with the chrome brower. Without this deep linking process, how is it possible to do SSO with custom tabs ?

PS : Here's a video to explain my issue and the tests done https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-4uLpUv1lA

Comment: It seems to be a bug in ChromeCustomTabs. I opened a ticket on googlecode here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=580069

Comment: I think it happens is due to the second redirect not being a result of a user action. Eg: on the first one, the user clicks the login button, and then the user is redirected. On the second one, the server issues an automatic redirect, as the user is already logged in and chrome doesn't follow it.

Comment: I agree with you. But that's kind of annoying as Oauth code flow cannot be used properly with custom tabs. I just read the following post that seems interesting https://paul.kinlan.me/deep-app-linking-on-android-and-chrome/#comment-2464645446. "the redirect only works if the user clicks on the same domain that will then try to start the intent." I'll try to change my redirect url to see if this solution is working.

Comment: The Chrome developer team seems to have fixed this bug with the latest chrome release (48+). See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=580069.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug fixed with the latest chrome release : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=580069